# duvida com angularjs, input e metodo onblur()

Tags: angularjs

Como faço para um input chamar uma função?

O campo é um cep, quero que quando o usuario sair desse campo, seja chamado a função `getCep()`.

Sei que no `JavaScript` tem a função `onblur`, mas com `AngularJs` não achei um jeito de fazer isso.

Comment: Para um input chamar uma função não é necessario chamar o Angular, a nao ser que voce queira alterar o estado de um objeto no angular,, portanto basta chamar `<input onblur="SuaFuncao();" />`

Answer (score 5):

Se a sua função estiver dentro do escopo de seu controller, você pode fazer simplesmente, usando o [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur):

```
 <input type="text" ng-blur="getCep()">
```

Caso não esteja, faça com o `onBlur` mesmo:

```
 <input type="text" onblur="getCep()">
```

### Exemplo

```js
function controller($scope){
  $scope.getCep = function(){
   $scope.demo = $scope.cep;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="controller" >
  
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="cep" 
       ng-blur="getCep()"
       ng-focus="demo = ''"
 ><br>
{{demo}}
  
</div>
```

No exemplo acima apenas simulei a função `getCep()` fazendo que ela mostra o que foi digitado ao dar um *blur* na caixa de texto. Da mesma forma usei o `ng-focus` para deixar a `var demo` vazia.

Comment: deu certo amigão, muito obrigado.