# Como utilizar o onBlur do Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

Quero que seja exibido no `console` o valor `cep` que digitei no campo `input` após o campo perder o foco.
Porém, esse meu código não está fazendo isso.

html:

```
<body ng-controller="appController">
<div align="center">
    <form>
        <label>CEP </label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cep" ng-blur="pegaCep(endereco)"><br>
        <label>Estado </label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.estado"><br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http){
    var pegaCep = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    pegaCep()
});
```

Comment: Gustavo, imagino que sua pergunta já possui uma resposta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108712/duvida-com-angularjs-input-e-metodo-onblur/108713#108713.

Comment: O código desse outro post, pra mim, não deu certo... Ficava aparecendo no console que o meu pegaCep não tinha sido definido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $http){
  $scope.pegaCep = function () {
    console.log($scope.endereco.cep);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="appController">
<div   align="center">
    <form>
        <label>CEP </label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.cep" ng-blur="pegaCep()"><br>
        <label>Estado </label><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="endereco.estado"><br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```